# How to use Dig command for saving results in Ubuntu

Tags: dns

I just found DIG command in Ubuntu which i want to use to bulk check Nameservers of domains .

Its working fine but one issue i am facing is there is no option to save output results .

Example : I am running this command to run tool :

```
$ dig +nocmd -f domains.txt ns +noall +answer
```

It runs and gives all results but i want them in txt file .

Please help .

Answer (score 2):

Run your command with `>output.txt` at the end, or pipe to `tee`.

Example:

```
dig +nocmd -f domains.txt ns +noall +answer > output.txt
```

or

```
dig +nocmd -f domains.txt ns +noall +answer | tee output.txt
```

It will write output to the `output.txt` file in the current directory.

The difference is that the `tee` variant will send output to screen AND the file.

You can redirect output of any command this way.

Comment: this command is not working , when i input and enter it dont run and pressing enter takes me to next line instead of running .

Comment: @VconMx then you're doing something wrong.  You need to show us the *exact* command you are using.

Comment: What do you mean by "running"? It will write output to the file instead of the screen. Look into the file.

Comment: I changed the command. Now it will be both "running" and writing to the file.